# How can I set hotkey for Windows Context Menu item?

Tags: windows, registry, contextmenu, clipboard, clipboarddata

I use [PasteIntoFile](https://github.com/MaxMls/PasteIntoFile/tree/863e157d15e0185513dbdc8d5131ec615c2494b3) software to paste image from clipboard to file.
The software registers a menu item in Windows Context Menu: "Paste Into File"

I would like to assign a hotkey (for example CTRL+Y) to activate this function.
How can I do this in the registry? Thanks!

[image: Context Menu]

Comment: You write a program that calls RegisterHotKey on `Ctrl`+`Y` and performs an appropriate action when the key is pressed. The registry is not a programming language.

Comment: When I handle the keypress inside the application, then the target path parameter is not received. The context menu item save the initial folder (where the hotkey was pressed) into the registry and the app read it. This will be the path of the saved image. Therefore I need add hotkey to the context menu item inside the registry. "The registry is not a programming language. " Ok, in this case I would like a PS script to modify the hotkey in the registry. :)

Comment: Your program gets to decide what happens if you press Ctrl+Y just out of the blue when focus is on, say, Notepad.

Comment: In this case, no, because the information from which folder the command was executed will be lost if the application handles the keypress. For example:
1. / If the command executed from context menu: When I execute it from "C:\Temp" folder, then the app will reveice the "C:\Temp" folder into a variable. 2./ If the command executed by hotkey and the application catch the keypress: In this case I cannot send the current folder to the application, so the "C:\Temp" information will be lost.

Comment: Well, that's what happens when you create a global hotkey. Users can press them at any time. You could say "Well, I will ignore the key unless focus is on an Explorer window. If focus is on an Explorer window, then I will activate the Paste Into File operation on that folder." You'll have to design this feature yourself and then implement it. There is no premade implementation.

Comment: I thought there was a pre-made solution because several menu items have hotkeys in Windows context menu (CTRL+C, CTRL+V, CTRL+Z)... It's true that I didn't find a post on how to assign a hotkey to a context menu item either. That's why I asked the question. But if that's not possible, I have a plan B, but that's another topic.

Comment: That the hotkeys appear on the menus is coincidence, not causality. (Most programs show hotkeys on menu items just to give you a clue that they have a hotkey you can use.) The hotkeys themselves are implemented by each program manually. See: Accelerator tables.